# I need help solving a competition math problem.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

I was doing a practice test for a math competition, and I came across a problem I am unable to solve, and I have tried to get help, with no luck. I need to be able to solve it without a calculator too. The problem is: "If $x^2+1/x^2=3$ and $x > 0$, what is the value of $x+1/x$. Express your answer in simplest radical form." I tried manipulating the first equation and I end up with $x^4-3x^2+1=0$, and there is no way I can figure out how to factor it. I would appreciate any help I can get with this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $x^2 \frac{1}{x^2} = 1$. We could add 2 to both sides of the equation to complete the square. $$ (x + \frac{1}{x})^2 = 5$$

Comment: You mean $x^2 + \frac 1 {x^2}=3?$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo, I mean their product. It is corrected. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Can I get a more detailed explanation please?

Comment: $$x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 2 = 3 + 2 = 5$$ $$x^2 + x^2 \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2} = 5$$ $$(x+\frac{1}{x})^2 = 5$$ $$x + \frac{1}{x} = \sqrt{5}$$ given $x > 0$ @Spencer1O1

Comment: In my opinion, the OP would have benefited more from another hint than the full answer.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Let $y=x^2$, solve for $y$ using the quadratic formula.

After you get your $y$, you can solve for the corresponding $x$.

Comment: Can I get a more detailed explanation? I know the quadratic formula, but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: can you solve $y^2-3y+1=0$?